# Probability of Bingo first 5 numbers drawn spelling out BINGO?

Tags: probability

In standard Bingo (numbers 1 to 75 inclusive), what are the chances of the first 5 numbers drawn spelling out BINGO in that exact order?  That is B, then I, then N, then G, then O?

Is it just $(1/5)^5 = 1/3125$?

Comment: Yes 15 numbers per letter (B = 1..15, I = 16..30, ...).  The actual bingo playcard is not relevant.  I am asking about the person drawing the nunbers.  What are the chances of them drawing B-I-N-G-O on the first 5 draws and in the proper order (spelling out BINGO)?

Comment: On second thought about this, since the drawn numbers are not being replaced, I would think the answer is 15/75 * 15/74 * 15/73 * 15/72 * 15/71 is that correct?  I think that is something like 1 out of 2727 chances.